# Can I wear a kilt around Europe?

Tags: europe, backpacking, clothing, scotland

I have the idea of wearing my kilt whilst travelling around Europe. It will be a lighter fabric than the traditional woolen one as it would be too warm for summer in Europe.

**What is a kilt?**

[image]

<sup>*hint*: it's the thing he's wearing round his waist that looks like a skirt.</sup>

**Why?**

Kilts are quite functional for walking and travelling.  I am planning on getting [one of these](http://www.utilikilts.com/) when I travel.

Also I would like to see what reactions I get from people when travelling around Europe.

---

**Where am I going in Europe?**

http://www.tripline.net/trip/Eurotrip_Bruce-6031502460441004AB55F3DFBEB7A2DD

---

- So have any of you worn a unique piece of clothing associated with your country, e.g. a Stetson hat from Texas, USA or a beret from France?
- What were the reactions you got from doing this when in another country?
- Did you receive any trouble for doing so or did you get positive reactions?
- Do you think it could cause offense in some countries, e.g. bare legs are forbidden?

Comment: [Michael McIntyre on the invention of the kilt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YQIA_FEe3o)

Comment: I'm pretty sure bare hairy masculine legs are not forbidden per se, however you should excuse people averting their eyes, generally ignoring you, and in some rare cases gouging their eyes with red-hot pokes :-)

Comment: I think this is a cool idea. You'll draw a lot of attention in many places (especially outside big cities) but I can't think of any area in Europe where you would run into outright *trouble* with this.

Comment: I suggest you don't attempt to go through airport security wearing a kilt. Unless you enjoy that sort of thing.

Comment: I'm not a fashion adviser, but i think you also must wear an axe  to look cool in a kilt...

Comment: You also need a lacy shirt and a sporran, and a knife in your sock. Maybe a little bonnet with a ribbon.

Comment: @RedSonja Some aspects of the Sgian Dubh is discussed here https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81226/4188

Comment: Causing of offence **might** depend on whether you plan on the traditional underwear with this garment and how careful you are in wearing the kilt. (For those not in the know, traditional underwear with the kilt is none at all.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wore my kilt (heavyweight one) round Germany and I can heartily recommend it - I made many friends, had lots of drinks bought for me and got invited to a lot of events and parties as people could spot the Scotsman a mile off. I'm assuming you are Scottish - if not, you may get some hassle, potentially, for pretending to be one :-)

In the summer it can be a little uncomfortable as Europe can get a lot hotter than Scotland, and kilts were made for cold environments, but a lightweight one may well be fine.

I'm not sure how good they are for long distances - I ran a half marathon wearing one and ended up with bleeding welts across both legs. Very painful. Especially if it is raining - the edge of the kilt will become like razor blades!

Comment: I am Scottish but I am British , if you get what I mean :)

Comment: Also what did you wear with it , sports socks and trainers? I was thinking a nice pair of casual trainers and medium length white sports socks with a casual t shirt?

Comment: Sports socks, hiking boots and a Scotland rugby top :-)

Comment: You see though the rugby top is too much of a give away, i think I will stick to a plain white t. it will make them think harder!

Comment: As long as it's not a see-through top...

Comment: hahahahahahaha. I'm sure I do have a picture of me on stage wearing only a kilt and military boots. Oh, and a mask...