# Where can one observe the Crossrail Skulls?

Tags: london, archaeology

Somewhat related to this question: [Sgian Dubh during the London Social Season, do you have to check it in everywhere?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81226/sgian-dubh-during-the-london-social-season-do-you-have-to-check-it-in-everywher) there will be a constant stream of guests in and out for about 2 - 2 1/2 months.  Being annual visitors, most already know London from a long time back.  I think it would be great to refer them to see something discovered more recently.

"Crossrail" is a project to build a modern rail connection spanning the city from east to west and extending out from Bucks to Essex.  While excavating, workers found something like an ossuary, but containing only skulls (hence the name "[Crossrail Skulls](http://www.crossrail.co.uk/news/articles/roman-skulls-discovered-at-liverpool-street)").  The current theory is that the skulls once belonged to gladiators or Roman soldiers who were beheaded.

The research was done earlier this year by the [Museum of London Archaeology](http://www.mola.org.uk/) (MOLA), but this institution does excavation and research and is not a proper museum in the ordinary definition of the word.

So where are they? Where can somebody go and see them? I have Googled high and low without success.

Question: where can someone see the Crossrail Skulls?

Comment: It looks like there was a display in 2014 at the Crossrail offices: https://www.ianvisits.co.uk/blog/2014/02/15/see-human-skulls-dug-up-by-crossrail/

Comment: Ah, there's a big exihibit going to open next February: https://www.ianvisits.co.uk/blog/2016/09/13/largest-ever-crossrail-archeology-exhibition-to-open/  I found the link in the previous comment by looking at google images for skulls on exhibit rather than in the tunnels.

Comment: Exhibition opens 10 Feb 2017 at the Museum of London Docklands: http://www.museumoflondon.org.uk/news-room/press-releases/tunnel-archaeology-crossrail

Comment: Anything during the season?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Crossrail Skulls are not currently on display to the public, so no, you won't be able to take your guests to see them during the London Social Season.

As [@mkennedy and @AE commented, there is an exhibition being prepared](http://www.museumoflondon.org.uk/news-room/press-releases/tunnel-archaeology-crossrail) which will run from 10 February 2017 to 3 September 2017 covering the archaeology of Crossrail at the [Museum of London Docklands](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Museum+of+London+Docklands/@51.507654,-0.0259208,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x487602c7b0543655:0xfff66a923afecf31!8m2!3d51.5076507!4d-0.0237321) and will include:

> - Prehistoric flints found in North Woolwich, showing evidence for Mesolithic tool making 8,000 years ago
> - Tudor bowling ball found at the site of the Tudor King John’s Court manor house in Stepney Green
> - Roman iron horse shoes found near Liverpool Street Station
> - Medieval animal bone skates found near Liverpool Street Station
> - Late 19th century ginger and jam jars from the site of the Crosse & Blackwell bottling factory near Tottenham Court Road station
> - Human remains including one of the skeletons found near Liverpool Street Station from the 17th century Bedlam cemetery, which aDNA has shown died from the Plague.